# How do I use karabiner to define two Shift+L to enter a key?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

My current definition lets me input "<" when I tap `SHIFT_L`:

```
__KeyOverlaidModifier__ 
KeyCode::SHIFT_L,  
KeyCode::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::BACKQUOTE
```

But I want to change it so I have to press `SHIFT_L` twice. I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
__KeyOverlaidModifier__ 
KeyCode::SHIFT_L,  
KeyCode::SHIFT_L,  
KeyCode::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::BACKQUOTE
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured it out, I just had to use a different command:

```
__DoublePressModifier__ 
KeyCode::SHIFT_L,  
KeyCode::SHIFT_L, 
KeyCode::SHIFT_L, KeyCode::BACKQUOTE
```